# How to connect a dapp on private ethereum network

Tags: private-blockchain, dapps, network

I created a private ethereum network with 3 nodes kai i have also created a dapp. How i can connect my dapp with my private network?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Usually dapps interact with the blockchain through an API provider. You can enable the RPC port in one of nodes, or use another node that will it enabled.

For geth you have to add `--rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3"`. Then your users can add a custom connection to MetaMask to your RPC provider and they will be able to interact with your dapp.

Comment: I have a connection with metamaske but how i deploy the dapp in the private network? If you have a guide os something!~

Comment: You use the exact same procedure than on mainnet but with your RPC provider. To deploy you can use Remix, Truffle or any other framework if they are connected to your nodes.

Comment: I found a guide with web3deploy  for the contract but what about the front end?

Comment: If the frontend is a web application then the deployment is exactly the same than any other web application. Your customers will need to use MetaMask and configure with your RPC. Another option is to embed your RPC address in your app so you do not depend on Metamask but you have to provide some kind of account management (that is not trivial task).

Comment: i want to do it without truffle. Do you know any guide that can help me?

Comment: There are a lot of articles and videos about the subject. Search a read/watch all that you can make sure they are recent (ie less than a year old). Do not stay with a single source but try many sources until you find one that you like.

Comment: I did it and i have find more but nothing specific for my situation. That's why i came here